# Base64 no the same result using Arduino and Java library

Tags: java, arduino, base64

why I am not geting the same result after encoding a string in base64 with JAVA and arduino library

Arduino code:

```
char data[] = "0123456789012345";
int inputLen = sizeof(data);
char encoded[100];
base64_encode(encoded, data, inputLen);

Serial.print("encoded base 64:");
Serial.println(encoded);
```

Arduino code result

```
encoded base 64:MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NQA=
```

Java code:

```
static String message= "0123456789012345";
/////
String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(message.getBytes());
System.out.println("encoded value is \t" + encoded);
```

Java code result:

```
encoded value is    MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NQ==
```

Why is the arduino library adding extra data at the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because strings are null-terminated. Consequently, when you write

```
char data[] = "0123456789012345";
```

you allocate a 17-bytes string, with an hex content of

```
0x30 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36 0x37 0x38 0x39 0x30 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x00
```

The function is adding also the terminal byte in the base64 encoding. If you want to discard it, change your line to

```
int inputLen = sizeof(data) - 1;
```

Comment: A better way would be to use `strlen`. If his `data` variable would be defined as `char data[20] = "0123456789012345";`, your solution would encode 19 character instead of 17.

Comment: @gre_gor it depends on why you defined data as 20 bytes. If you wanted to actually send 20 bytes, then the only solution is to use `inputLen = sizeof(data)` (without the -1). Moreover the `sizeof` information is added at compile time, while the `strlen` is computed at runtime (so it's slower and bigger). Of course if you have a variable string length you have to use `strlen`, but since the OP didn't use that function I assume he never has to change it.